# How to fold the class block in Vim?

Tags: vim, macvim

I know zR/zM/za are used to fold/unfold everything or blocks. But are there any ways to fold the specific class in Vim if there are several classes in same file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `:set foldmethod=indent`.

This command will create folds automatically by the indent of the lines.